# What is the electrolytic bath used in gold-plating of copper articles?

Tags: electrochemistry

The answer is $AuCl_3 + NaCN$

Now I understand that for electroplating, we need gold to be deposited on the copper article, and the electrolyte must enable that deposition. But I don’t know what is the use of $NaCN$ in the process.

Also, if copper is the cathode, then pure gold should be the anode. But the oxidation potential of gold is very low, then how does it get dissolved in the solution.

Can I get an explanation on this process would work?

Comment: There are several cyanide processes for gold plating. Just do some searching and you will find them.

Comment: @EdV I don’t know how appropriate it is to ask, but can I get an upvote? I really need it. It isn’t ethical to do so, but I need one.

Comment: I can ethically upvote if you flesh out the question text. Look up the cyanide process for gold extraction. Once you see that, you will know why cyanide is used. Fair enough? By the way, why would anyone actually *need* an upvote? There is nothing in the real world riding on stack exchange rep, after all.

Comment: @EdV You see, I am on a question ban here, for a few bad questions 6 months ago. Now I agree, it’s totally my fault, but I was a new user, and SE is a really harsh place for such people. But I know how to use the site properly now (I be over 2000 rep on Math), but the system won’t lift the ban until I get an upvote (at least, that’s what I could make out from the guidelines). So yes, it’s kind of important, or else it will ban me for another 6 months